# How to make a chart with a string values instead of data?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

I'm currently trying to create the chart using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) library.
It should looks smth like that: [image: chart]

I have object with values, like

```
{
   January: "A",
   February: "B",
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to map data (type - number) with a letter through the following map that I've created:

```
export const mapCodes = {
  A: {
    value: 8
  },
  B: {
    value: 7
  },
  C: {
    value: 6
  },
  D: {
    value: 5
  },
  E: {
    value: 4
  },
  F: {
    value: 3
  },
  G: {
    value: 2
  },
  NP: {
    value: 1
  },
  TD: {
    value: 1
  },
};
```

The data I want do display: `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1]` - it is equal to 6 letters "C" and 3 "NP/TD".

For now, I achieved the following result:
[image: chart]

6 - is a max data value and it is showing on the chart. I'm trying also to show on Y-scale letters "A" and "B".

Code:

```
    const yLabels = {
      1: 'TD/NP',
      2: 'G',
      3: 'F',
      4: 'E',
      5: 'D',
      6: 'C',
      7: 'B',
      8: 'A',
    }

    this.barChartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return yLabels[value];
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

Can I display more values on Y-axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the ticks callback to customize the labels.

here, I associate each value with a letter.

```
A = 4
B = 3
C = 2
D = 1
```

then replace the value with the letter in the callback...

```
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(value) {
          var axisLabels = 'DCBA';

          // do not include ticks with decimal places
          if ((value > 0) && (value.toFixed(0)) === value.toString()) {
            return axisLabels.charAt(value - 1);
          }
          return null;
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart');
  var data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Series',
      data: [4, 3, 2, 1],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)"
    }]
  }
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            callback: function(value) {
              var axisLabels = 'DCBA';

              // do not include ticks with decimal places
              if ((value > 0) && (value.toFixed(0)) === value.toString()) {
                return axisLabels.charAt(value - 1);
              }
              return null;
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
```

---

**EDIT**

you can use the following options,
to ensure ticks are drawn for all values in the map...

```
suggestedMin: 1,
suggestedMax: 8,
```

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart');
  var data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Series',
      data: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  }

  const yLabels = {
    1: 'TD/NP',
    2: 'G',
    3: 'F',
    4: 'E',
    5: 'D',
    6: 'C',
    7: 'B',
    8: 'A',
  }

  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              suggestedMin: 1,
              suggestedMax: 8,
              stepSize: 1,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return yLabels[value];
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it possible to include values from "A" to "G"?

Comment: and only several of them have got values

Comment: yes, you can include A to G, just a matter of adjusting the callback function. I don't really follow your second comment. And I just realized, I didn't address the data sample you provided. can you provide a larger sample of the actual data? I will edit my answer to incorporate...

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if it is clear :)